# Как дописать метод фильтрации списка?

Tags: ruby

Необходимо дописать метод М, для того, чтобы тот фильтровал список фильмов по паре ключ-значение.

```
puts films.m(genre: 'Comedy') 

class Movie

 attr_reader :url, :title, :year, :country, :date, :genre, :length, :rating, :director, :actors

  def initialize(row)
    @url = row[0]
    @title = row[1]
    @year = row[2]
    @country = row[3]
    @date = row[4]
    @genre = row[5].to_s
    @length = row[6].to_i
    @rating = row[7]
    @director = row[8]
    @actors = row[9]
  end

  def has_genre?(field)
      @genre.include?(field)
  end

  def to_s
      "#{@title} (#{@year}), #{@genre} - #{@director}; #{@actors}" 
  end
end


____movielist.rb

require 'csv'
require 'date'
require 'ostruct'

require_relative 'movie.rb'
KEYS = [:url, :title, :year, :country, :date, :genre, :length, :rating, :director, :actors]

class MoviesCollection 

  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename
    @movies = CSV.read(filename, col_sep: '|', write_headers: :true, headers: KEYS).
      map{|film| Movie.new(film)}
  end

  def all
    puts @movies.first(5) #all films
  end

  def sort_by (field) # sort by any field
    @movies.
      sort_by {|movie| movie.send(field)}
  end

  def m(filters)
  filters.each do |key, val| 
   @movies.select {???



  def except_genre (genre)  #delete genre
    @movies.
      select{|movie| !movie.has_genre?(genre)}.
      map{|movie| movie.title + " " + movie.genre.to_s}
  end

  def stats(field)
    if field == "date"
      @movies.map { |movie| (Date.parse(movie.date, '%Y-%m-%d').mon if movie.date.length == 10) }.compact.
        group_by{|i| i}.collect{|month, group| [month, group.count]}.to_h.sort.
        map{ |month, quant| Date::MONTHNAMES[month] + ' - ' + quant.to_s }
    else
      @movies.map{|movie| movie.send(field)}.
       sort_by{|field| field}.group_by{|field| field}.
       map{|field, group| [field, group.count]}
  end
end
end

__mov.rb

require_relative 'movielist.rb'
require_relative 'movie.rb'


filename = "movies.txt"
films = MoviesCollection.new(filename) 


puts
puts films.all # весь массив

puts
puts films.sort_by("title").first(5) # сортировка по заданному полю

puts 
puts films.m(genre: 'Comedy') # фильмы определенного жанра + сортировка по стране

puts
puts films.except_genre("Sci-Fi").first(5) #фильмы за исключением определенного жанра, отсортированные по дате

puts 
puts films.stats("date").first(5) # кол-во фильмов по запрашеваемому полю
```

Comment: Что выступает в качестве ключа, а что в качестве значения? Сортировка обычно осуществляется либо по ключу, либо по значению, можете точно сообщить как сортируем тут?

Comment: @cheops Мы сортируем по паре ключ-значение
puts films.m(genre: 'Comedy'), к примеру
и так соответственно для любого поля

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
def m(filters)
  res = []
  filters.each do |key, val|
    res += @movies.select { |x| x.send(key) == val }
  end
  res
end
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Метод работает

Comment: а если необходимо сделать, чтобы возможно было использовать несколько сочетаний ключ-значение для фильтрации?
puts films.m(genre:'Comedy', year: '1993')

Comment: М-м, самодельный `reduce` :)

Comment: @Артур делать выборку не из `@movies`, а результата прошлого шага, и **не добавлять** к результату, а **перезаписывать** его.